# Classic singleton vs. Lazy with Java 8 Performance

Tags: performance, java-8, jmh

Recently I read an article "[Be Lazy With Java 8](http://minborgsjavapot.blogspot.co.il/2016/01/be-lazy-with-java-8.html)", which introduced a way to create a lazy objects (objects that will created their internal state on the first access).

```
public final class Lazy<T> {

    private volatile T value;

    public T getOrCompute(Supplier<T> supplier){
        final T result = value;
        return result == null ? maybeCompute(supplier) : result;
    }

    private synchronized T maybeCompute(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        if (value == null){
            value = Objects.requireNonNull(supplier.get());
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

I found this pattern to be very similar to the well-known singleton pattern, except the generics:

```
public class PropertiesSingleton {

    public static Properties getProperties(){
        return Helper.INSTANCE;
    }

    private final static class Helper{
        private final static Properties INSTANCE = computeWithClassLoaderLock();


        private static Properties computeWithClassLoaderLock(){
            return new Properties();
        }
    }
}
```

The Lazy class uses **volatile** member to synchronize access to the internal object while the singleton pattern has few implementations (I personally prefer to use it with inner helper class that have one static final member). I assumed that the second pattern have better performance since each call to *getOrCompute* method on Lazy object involve a read from the main memory (due to volatile member) while the Singleton loaded once by the class loader cached in L1 & L2 memory caches.
I used [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) benchmark to test my assumption on **CentOS 6 with Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz**. The benchmark can be downloaded from my Git repository: https://github.com/maximkir/LazyObjectVsSingletonPerformance

Here are the results table:

```
Benchmark                                   Mode      Cnt   Score   Error  Units
LazyVsSingletonPerformance.testLazy       sample  1101716  33.793 ± 0.148  ns/op
LazyVsSingletonPerformance.testSingleton  sample   622603  33.993 ± 0.179  ns/op
```

The results show that no difference between the two options, I am not understanding why. I would expect that the second pattern will perform better. Any ideas? inlining? Compiler optimization? Wrong benchmark test?

**The Benchmark code:**

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class LazyVsSingletonPerformance {

    Blackhole bh = new Blackhole();
    Lazy<Properties> lazyProperties = new Lazy<>();

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{
        Options opts = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(LazyVsSingletonPerformance.class.getSimpleName())
                .warmupIterations(3)
                .forks(2)
                .measurementIterations(3)
                .mode(Mode.SampleTime)
                .measurementTime(TimeValue.seconds(10))
                .timeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
                .build();

        new Runner(opts).run();
    }


    @Benchmark
    public void testLazy(){
        bh.consume(lazyProperties.getOrCompute(() -> new Properties()));
    }


    @Benchmark
    public void testSingleton(){
        bh.consume(PropertiesSingleton.getProperties());
    }
```

Comment: By the way, here is the original source for the DZone article, for future reference: http://minborgsjavapot.blogspot.com/2016/01/be-lazy-with-java-8.html

Comment: It seems to me that - after warm up - you finally compare just the access to either volatile member (which never changes and is not null) or to constant member of holder class. So you are not really measuring the initialization part of those members (after a lot of invocations).

Comment: The initialization is not important since it takes place only once.

Comment: Indeed, initialization is not relevant here in measurements. But then, why do you expect a bigger difference?

Comment: since every call to getOrCompute involves a read from the main memory which is slower than reading from caches (I assume that this is the case in the PropertiesSingleton  class).

Comment: constants like `Helper.INSTANCE` are visible for all threads, so they are obviously in main memory, too.

Comment: My suspicion about volatiles: If they are updated then the synchronization of the local thread cache with the main memory might become expensive. But the access to main memory itself does not need to be expensive, and your volatile is never updated after initialization.

Comment: @MaximKirilov can you try to make your test methods return `Properties` instead of using the black hole.  Does that make a difference in the result?

Comment: I'm no JMH expert but isn't the overhead of the method calls much higher than the field accesses? You would then be only measuring overhead… What difference does it make for a method that just returns `null` instead of the singleton?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in concurrency, but it seems that your Lazy initializer is incorrect. In benchmark you use `Scope.Thread` state. But that means that each thread will have it's own Lazy, so there is no real concurrency.

I wrote my own benchmark with Lazy (based on apache commons [LazyInitializer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/LazyInitializer.html)), Eager and static inner class.

Eager
    package org.sample;

```
import java.util.Properties;

public class Eager {
    private final Properties value = new Properties();

    public Properties get(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Lazy
    package org.sample;

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.ConcurrentException;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.LazyInitializer;

import java.util.Properties;

public class Lazy extends LazyInitializer<Properties> {
    @Override
    protected Properties initialize() throws ConcurrentException {
        return new Properties();
    }
}
```

PropertiesSingleton is as yours.

Benchmark
    package org.sample;

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.ConcurrentException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;

import java.util.Properties;

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class MyBenchmark {
    private Lazy lazyProperties = new Lazy();
    private Eager eagerProperties = new Eager();

    @Benchmark
    public Properties testEager(){
        return eagerProperties.get();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public Properties testLazy() throws ConcurrentException {
        return lazyProperties.get();
    }    

    @Benchmark
    public Properties testSingleton(){
        return PropertiesSingleton.getProperties();
    }
}
```

Results

```
Benchmark                   Mode  Cnt         Score         Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testEager      thrpt   20  90980753,160 ± 4075331,777  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testLazy       thrpt   20  83876826,598 ± 3445507,139  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testSingleton  thrpt   20  82260350,608 ± 3524764,266  ops/s
```